Show number of card element in NavMenu in Blazor C#
I learn C# (.NET 6.0) with Blazor and I try to display number of Card item on NavMenu.
I tried use some EventCallback or Object inheritance on page to send event to NavMenu and update value, but it not work.
Do you have any idea or suggestion on how I can achieve the expected effect?
Example:
/Pages/Counter.razor
@page "/counter"

@using Blazored.SessionStorage
@inject ISessionStorageService sessionStorageService
@inject MenuInformation MenuInformation

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Counter > IncrementCount");
        currentCount++;
        MenuInformation.SetCount(currentCount);
        base.StateHasChanged();
        
        InvokeAsync(() => { StateHasChanged(); });
        
    }
}

/MenuInformation.cs
namespace TestSession
{
    public class MenuInformation
    {
        public int count { get; private set; } = 0;
        public void SetCount(int value)
        {
            if (!string.Equals(count, value)) 
            {
                count = value;
                NotifyDataChanged();
            }
        }
        public event Action OnChange;
        public void NotifyDataChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
    }
}

/Shared/NavMenu.razor
@using Blazored.SessionStorage
@inject MenuInformation MenuInformation
...
<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <nav class="flex-column">
...
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
                <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
            </NavLink>
        </div>
...
        <p style="color: white">COUNTER: @childCount</p>
    </nav>
</div>
...
@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private string? NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private int? childCount = null;
    void ClickHandler(int val)
    {
        childCount = val;
    }
    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("NavMenu > OnParametersSetAsync");
        childCount = MenuInformation.count;
    }
}

I can not pass value from page to NavMenu, and refresh NavMenu after button click.
I expect that after pressing the button, the current value will be transferred to NavMenu and visible on the page.
Please give me a tip or a reference to an article that will help me solve this problem.

Change Counter.razor to:
@page "/counter"

@using Blazored.SessionStorage
@inject ISessionStorageService sessionStorageService
@inject MenuInformation MenuInformation

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @MenuInformation.count</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Counter > IncrementCount");
        MenuInformation.SetCount(MenuInformation.count + 1);
    }
}

and NavMenu.razor to:
@using Blazored.SessionStorage
@implements IDisposable
@inject MenuInformation MenuInformation
...
<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <nav class="flex-column">
...
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
                <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
            </NavLink>
        </div>
...
        <p style="color: white">COUNTER: @MenuInformation.count</p>
    </nav>
</div>
...
@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private string? NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        MenuInformation.OnChange += OnChangeHandler;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        MenuInformation.OnChange -= OnChangeHandler;
    }

    private async void OnChangeHandler()
    {
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
}

Documentation: In-memory state container service
